# Table wont paste into google docs and preserve borders with a class. Only with direct style with firefox

Tags: php, html, css, google-docs

I am a little perplexed here.

I have this CSS + HMTL code:

```css
table.header {
   width:100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.header td {
   border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<table class='header'>
<tr>
<td style=''>Total Mem</td>
<td style=''>Used</td>
<td style=''>Free</td>
<td style=''>Shared</td>
<td style=''>Buffers</td>
<td style=''>Cache</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And it display my sample table like expected:

[image: Image of above code]

If I cut and paste that table into a google doc, I lose borders, colors etc ..

However. If I apply the styling at each td instead of using the class, I get the exact same results on the web page but this time it copies all the styling into the google doc.

```html
<table class='header'>
<tr>
<td style='border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;'>Total Mem</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;'>Used</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;'>Free</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;'>Shared</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;'>Buffers</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; background-color:#EEE; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;'>Cache</td>
</table>
```

I am at a loss here. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I don't understand, those look like php code that prints out html. and where do you put your css? if you just copy paste html, then css won't be there.

Comment: yes. it is php. the css is loaded at the top which i don't include in my question. i just put the snippet of code to show. but the css is loading properly. Only in firefox is this an issue.